# Network communication between containers in different Docker Compose applications running simultaneously

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there any way that a container X in docker-compose application A can communicate with a container Y in docker-compose application B, both running simultaneously.

I wish to deliver my application as a `docker-compose.yml` file. This is docker-compose application A. The application requires that certain databases exist. In production, clients must provide these database and inform the application of the required access information.

Here is an runnable *simulation* of my production deliverable `docker-compose.yml` file. It provides a service, but needs access to an external Postgres database, configured via three environment variables.

```
# A
version: '3'

services:

  keycloak:
      image: jboss/keycloak:11.0.3
      environment:
        DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
        DB_ADDR: ${MYAPP_KEYCLOAK_POSTGRES_ADDR}:${MYAPP_KEYCLOAK_POSTGRES_PORT}
        DB_DATABASE: keycloak
        DB_USER: keycloak
        DB_SCHEMA: public
        DB_PASSWORD: "${MYAPP_KEYCLOAK_POSTGRES_PASSWORD}"
        KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
        KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: changeme
        PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: "true"

# Other services ...
```

Clients run the application with `docker-compose up` with the three environment variables set to those of a *client provided* Postgres database.

For *development*, I compose the required Postgres databases inside the Docker Compose application, using the following `docker-compose.yml` file. This composition runs out the box.

```
# DEV
version: '3'


volumes:
  dev-keycloak_postgres_data:
      driver: local

services:

  dev-keycloak-postgres:
      image: postgres:11.5
      volumes:
        - dev-keycloak_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
        POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: keycloak-postgres-changeme

# DELIVERABLES

  keycloak:
      image: jboss/keycloak:11.0.3
      environment:
        DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
        DB_ADDR: dev-keycloak-postgres:5432
        DB_DATABASE: keycloak
        DB_USER: keycloak
        DB_SCHEMA: public
        DB_PASSWORD: keycloak-postgres-changeme
        KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
        KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: keycloak-admin-changeme
        PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: "true"
      depends_on:
        - dev-keycloak-postgres

# Other services ...
```

While using containerized Postgres is not suitable for production, I would like to provide my clients with a *demonstration* required environment, in the form of a separate `docker-compose.yml` file, providing the required external infrastructure, in this example, a single containerized Postgres. The is Docker Compose application B.

```
# B
version: '3'

# For demonstration purposes only! Not production ready!

volumes:
  demo-keycloak_postgres_data:
      driver: local

services:

  demo-keycloak-postgres:
      image: postgres:11.5
      volumes:
        - demo-keycloak_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
        POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: keycloak-postgres-changeme
```

The demonstration required infrastructure application B is delivered and managed completely independently to the real deliverable application A. It needs to be up and running before application A starts.

Suppose the respective docker-compose files are in subfolders A and B respectively.

To start application B, I change into folder B and run `docker-compose up`.

To start application A, in another terminal I change into folder A, and run `docker-compose up` with the three environment variables set.

I hoped the following values would work, given the behaviour of the DEV `docker-compose.yml` above:

```
export ICT4APP_KEYCLOAK_POSTGRES_ADDR="demo-keycloak-postgres"
export ICT4APP_KEYCLOAK_POSTGRES_PORT="5432"
export ICT4APP_KEYCLOAK_POSTGRES_PASSWORD="keycloak-postgres-changeme"
docker-compose up
```

But no! Cearly `ICT4APP_KEYCLOAK_POSTGRES_ADDR="demo-keycloak-postgres"` is wrong.

- Is there any way a container X in docker-compose application A can communicate with a container Y in docker-compose application B, and if so, can I determine the correct value for `ICT4APP_KEYCLOAK_POSTGRES_ADDR`

---

I am trying to avoid a -f solution for this particular use case.

Comment: You can have the 2 parts of the application in separate docker-compose files in the same directory. If you start them with `docker-compose -f <compose-file> up -d`, docker-compose will connect them to the same network and the containers can talk to each other using the service names like you would if they were in the same compose file.

Comment: @HansKilian Thank you. I was aware of that feature and was particularly trying to avoid if possible. I will update the OP.

Comment: To be honest, neither -f nor external network is perfect for my needs. But thanks for the input.

Comment: You can name the main file 'docker-compose.yml'. That way you only have to use `-f` for the optional one. But yeah, it's not ideal. Compose complains about orphaned containers when you bring it up and that there are still connected containers on the network when you bring it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an external network and assign it to both containers in compose-file a and b.

```
docker network create external-net
```

and in your docker-compose.yml add to the end

```
networks:
  external-net:
    external:
      name: external-net
```

Comment: sorry, my bad. I missed the third line. I corrected my answer. And yes you have to add it to both compose-files.

Comment: Please note we need *version: '3.5'* and may I suggest the following  instead, which requires no changes to each containers  *networks:
  default:
    name: external-net
    external: true*